# How to change WordPress header x frame option SAMEORIGIN TO ALLOWALL OR Specific URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

[Here is the image proff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKc4W.png)

```
function send_frame_options_header() {
  header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' );
}
```

How to change this function by filter or by the plugin?

I need to change ALLOW All

is it possible through a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This `send_frame_options_header()` function is called as a WordPress action handler on two different hooks.

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

and

```php
add_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

If you set your own action handler for those hooks, and give them a higher priority than `10`, you can override what they do by calling header_remove(). Put these lines of code into a plugin or snippet or something.

```php
function fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header () {
  header_remove( 'X-Frame-Options' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header', 11, 0 );
add_action( 'login_init', 'fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header', 11, 0 );
```

Notice the priority `11`. You want your hook function to run after the core function.

The [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) doesn't, any more, have an Allow variant. If you want to specify which domains' iframe code can embed your page, you need to use the content security policy [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive.

Add a line to your hook function. This allows your pages to be embedded by your own site and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

```php
function fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header () {
  header_remove( 'X-Frame-Options' );
  header( "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.example.com;" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you support but i followed this brother and its wont work       
                                                                                                                          
    

`add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );


function fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header () {
  header_remove( 'X-Frame-Options' );

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header ', 11, 0 ); ` 



Added this but its iframe is there .....how to resolve it brother

Comment: have you tried this before ? cuz its not working ... maybe not supporting to current new version wordpress

Comment: Oh, sorry, there are typos.  I put extra spaces after the function names in the `add_action()` calls. Edited. With the fix this works for me.

Comment: i have removed space also , but wont work brother , can you send me function.php with these codes ?

Comment: I would never, in a million years, suggest that anyone edit `functions.php` or help them do it. I suggest you use the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin to add this kind of code to your site.

Comment: actually i have a custom plugin, i am doing by the plugin , i tried its wont work brother

Comment: If you want this on your audience-visible pages try using the `init` action in place of the other ones. This may do it.  `add_action( 'init', 'fasal_basha_send_frame_options_header', 11, 0 );`

Comment: not working brother , if possible anydesk connection ?